# Enable ACL for eCryptFS mounted home directory

Tags: ubuntu, access-control-list, ecryptfs

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 with the "encrypt home directory" feature. This uses eCryptFS  to encrypt and mount my home directory. Now I need to enable ACL for this mount but since it's not configured in /etc/fstab I don't know how to do that.

Enabling ACL for my / mount doesn't do anything for me. These are two of mount mounts:

```
$ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,acl,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)
/home/tobias/.Private on /home/tobias type ecryptfs (ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_sig=2be72e2e03c0d2a1,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=f8f38af9c5e2c0e2)
```

Any ideas on how to enable ACL for /home/tobias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eCryptFS does not support ACLs, but apparently there are some people working on that.

See: http://130.245.27.2/~rdhaliwal/Final_Report.pdf

> THE file system eCryptfs aims at providing advanced  security
>   mechanism for file systems using existing  cryptographic technologies.
>   It provides several policy features  but does not provide Access
>   Control List (ACL) support.

http://ankushgulati.weebly.com/projects.html

Comment: Thanks. That sucks to hear but at least it answers my question.